# XPath and XMLs with namespaces

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfAgence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns="http://www.artos.co.il/">
  <Agence>
    <CodeAval>20008</CodeAval>
    <CodeSource>ArtPO</CodeSource>
    <LogicielSource>NTLIS</LogicielSource>
</Agence>
</ArrayOfAgence>
```

I want to get the CodeAval value, so I tried:

```
ArrayOfAgence/Agence/CodeAval
```

It obviously didn't work since this XML has a namespace, so, how do I need to approach this?

Thanks,

Comment: Firs exact duplicate found [XPATHS and Default Namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345/xpaths-and-default-namespaces)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that you use this XPath in XSLT. In that case you need to add a namespace definition with a prefix for the input documents default namespace `http://www.artos.co.il/` and then use this prefix in your XPath expression.

Example of namespace definition (it doesn't need to be in the `stylesheet` element)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:artos="http://www.artos.co.il/">
```

Example of the prefix usage in the XPath expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="artos:ArrayOfAgence/artos:Agence/artos:CodeAval"/>
```

Note the added prefix in front of every element name.

Answer (score 4):

If your XPath library is namespace aware (which yours seems to be) then it should provide you with a way to alias namespaces.

For example, if you're using Java, then the `javax.xml.xpath.XPath` object has a `setNamespaceContext(NamespaceContext context)` method which lets you provide a namespace resolver.

So, you might tell it that `a` is an alias for the namespace `http://www.artos.co.il/`, and then your query would become `a:ArrayOfAgence/a:Agence/a:CodeAval`

Comment: I'm just trying to create an XSL, not using lib

Comment: In which case you just add the namespace to your `xsl:stylesheet` element.