# How to use custom msbuild properties to set variables in code?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am trying to set a C# variable (string) to be compiled during the call to msbuild using the "/p" argument:

`msbuild.exe mysolution.sln -p:MyCustomProperty=MyCustomValue`

However, I'm stuck on how to access this "MyCustomProperty" value (MyCustomValue) in C# code...  I was hoping for something simple like using an Attribute like this:

```
[GetAProjectPropertyAttribute("MyCustomProperty")]
public string MyVariable = "";
```

But I don't know if such an attribute exists?  Are C# project properties not accessible during the compile to set certain code statements?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is no such attribute available. You can write that property values to configuration file during msbuild and c#code can read it from configuration file at runtime when program runs.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, do you have an example of "writing that property value to configuration file during msbuild and C# code reading it from configuration file at runtime?"

Comment: You can use XmlUpdate task in your build script... to write data to XML file... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175160/xmlupdate-task-not-updating-my-xml-file

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is better solution, but if you have just few options you can use this (tags are for .NET MAUI project)

csproj

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(MyCustomProperty)'=='Value1'">
  <DefineConstants>A</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(MyCustomProperty)'=='Value2'">
  <DefineConstants>B</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

argument of build command

```
-p:MyCustomProperty=Value1
```

C# code

```
#if A
//do something
#elif B
//do something else
#endif
```